# How to find find $f(x)$ such that $f'(x)=\sin^2(x)$ & $f\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=\frac{\pi}{4}$?

Tags: functions

I need to find $f(x)$ such that $f'(x)=\sin^2(x)$ & $f\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=\frac{\pi}{4}$. How to do it?

Comment: **Hint::** $$\int f'(x) = f(x) + \mathcal C$$ and you can eliminate that $\mathcal C$ using the f(x) value you already know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$f(x)=\int \sin^2{x}dx=\int\dfrac{1-\cos{(2x)}}{2}=\dfrac{x}{2}-\dfrac{\sin{2x}}{4}+C$$
since
$$f(\dfrac{\pi}{2})=\dfrac{\pi}{4}\Longrightarrow C=0$$